# Nhibernate eager fetch for children -> grand children

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Searching the net for this one for the past 2 hours. Any help is greatly appreciated.
 The scenario is like this, we have a **Questionnaire**, witch has **Steps**, each step has **input sets**, each input set has **questions**.

A simple QuestionnaireRepository.Session.Get(id) will further on result in multiple queries when accessing different collections. I was hoping I can get them all in one trip to the database.

Thanks,

PS. Of course we will want to have a small dataset :D

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten ok results with my solution from here: [nhibernate : how to intialise child list objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841248/nhibernate-how-to-intialise-child-list-objects/2841358#2841358)

BUT for anything but the smallest datasets, this will not perform very well, and I would recommend to denormalize.

Comment: going 1 deep is fine, but how about 2 or 3 levels down ? like I what to do for input sets and then for questions ?

Comment: The solution I linked to goes 3 levels down.